# Copy files from ext3 USB flash drive on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, mount, ext3

I have a USB flash with ext3fs partition on it. I want to open/copy files from this drive but Windows 8 obviously does not recognize it.

Acronis disk manager sees the drive and recognizes ext3 filesystem, but I can't open or copy any files with it.

How do I mount this drive on Windows 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up installing Paragon ExtFS for Windows, worked nicely for me!

Answer (score 0):

Install something like [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), which allows Windows to mount and read/write to ext file systems.

It claims to support Windows 8.

Simply download and run the .exe - it's a pretty easy install.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work unfortunately.